# How can I sort a TableView based on a substring of the data in that column

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

My table column ("ID") in which the celldata has some string and integers represented below.

**ID**
abc1
fgd5
hgt9
ftg7

I should get the following result after sort:

**ID**
abc1
fgd5
ftg7
hgt9

So how can I sort this column based on only the integer values in the column data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

```
TableColumn<SomeEntity, String> idColumn ;
```

You can do

```
// any number of non-digits (consumed greedily), 
// followed by any number of digits (consumed greedily, as a group named "value"),
// followed by anything
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\D*(?<value>\\d*).*");

idColumn.setComparator(Comparator.comparingInt(id -> {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(id);

    // value to return if no match:
    int defaultValue = 0 ;

   if (matcher.matches()) {
        // get the portion of the match that matched the group named "value":
        String value = matcher.group("value");
        if (value.isEmpty()) {
            return defaultValue ;
        } else {
            // convert to an int:
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
    } else {
        return defaultValue ;
    }
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this!